# Flutter how many items can be placed in AppBar before it overflows

Tags: dart, flutter

#### Question:

I have `actions` in my `AppBar` and I wanna know how many items I can safely put in there before the `AppBar` overflows.

#### Screenshot:

[image]

#### Code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Overflowing"),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_end), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_made), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_merge), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_received), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_missed), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_missed_outgoing), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call_split), onPressed: () {}),
    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear_all), onPressed: () {}),
  ],
),
```

Comment: There is a `Wrap` widget but it won't work in `AppBar`

Comment: why not add one Icon-button in the appbar and when it is clicked it shows a list of all those Icon-buttons below the appbar

Comment: Thanks for answering, I do know there is `PopupMenuButton` but my question is bit different. I want to place maximum number of items. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't `ListView` with horizontal direction suits you?

Comment: @Andrey First, is `ListView` usable in `actions`, second my use case is completely different my question just wants to get some clarity on how can we know if a widget is going to be overflowed. Thanks :)